# Changing the data on a loop on a Flask webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have my app.py as it follows:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def indexPage():

    return render_template('index.html')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Imagine I will have such a loop that it has to change every 1 sec as it follows:

```
while(True):
    i = i+1
```

and in this each iteration I have to return the data to my flask webpage.
I have researched about this and the answers are generally from 2012 which doesn't really work.

What HTML and JS format should I use to print this data to my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use server-side, i.e. flask, to do this (unless you use AJAX, but that seems a bit pointless). If you're starting out with JavaScript, maybe try [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) about [jQuery](https://jquery.com), which is a wrapper for js and is considered to make life easier when dealing with client side javascript. For a time function, you don't actually need to use jQuery; there is a JavaScript function called `getSeconds()`. You could make a function that checks if a second has passed and if it has, changes the HTML of the page (that's the bit that jQuery's good at).

Here's the Mozilla Dev docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds

Comment: I'll be having some predictions on real time, so I have to print them on my web page. Will AJAX help on that situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from your server to your web app you should check out [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)